# Function to multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-functions

I have this function, but I wanted to pass a table so as to use the same function to get the job done for multiple tables. For example, I want this function work for table1, and table2. But it is just for table1 currently. I was trying to use a dynamic sql in vain; it doesn't pass the parameter selected.
Can someone help? Give me guide on how to pass table as a parameter.

Sample data, table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id int identity (1,1), name varchar(60)) 
INSERT INTO table1
VALUES ('a1, a2, a9, a8')
```

Sample data, table2

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (id int identity (1,1), name varchar(60)) 
INSERT INTO table2
VALUES ('a1, a2, a9, a8')
```

The function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_split
(@id INT)    
RETURNS @ab 
TABLE (name VARCHAR(20),
ab1 VARCHAR(5)
)
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @temp TABLE (rn INT, name VARCHAR(5))
    INSERT INTO  @temp(rn, name)
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))) ASC) rn, LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))) Result
    FROM
    (
    SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE([name], ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
    FROM table1 where id = @id
    ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)
    ORDER BY 1
INSERT INTO @ab 
SELECT * FROM @temp 
RETURN
END
```

This gives the result from table1.

```
SELECT * FROM F_SPLIT(1)
```

But I want the same function to work for table2 as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try searching the Internet for the words ___sql server dynamic sql___?

Comment: I did and tried to apply that. But I don't think it works with function.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a partitioned view**, which will allow you to specify the table name as a parameter in the where clause.

Start by creating a view that unions the two tables, plus an additional column to indicate which table the row comes from.

```
CREATE VIEW BothTables AS
SELECT 'Table1' TableName, * FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table2' TableName, * FROM Table2
```

Then modify your function. When you pass the table name, use it to select a subset of rows from the view. So instead of

```
SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE([name], ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
FROM   table1
WHERE  id = @id
```

Use

```
SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE([name], ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
FROM   BothTables 
WHERE  TableName = @TableName 
AND    id = @id
```